# Preparing raster Image for correlation in ENVI 5.5

Tags: envi, correlation

I am working with two raster image of the same location with the same extent, both projected to the same coordinate system and having the same cell size. I want to correlate the raster value on the images using ENVI 5.5. I have classified the raster value of these images into two classes but I am interested in the correlation of only one class on both images. How do I extract the only class of interest on both images, thereby leaving other class as area of no data, before running the correlation?

Answer (score 0):

The said raster with two classes of pixels can be used to generate a shapefile. This shapefile is then used to mask this raster image by generating a mask image. The masked image is then used to extract the unwanted class of pixel from the raster image. With only pixel values for the remaining one class in the raster image, correlation can be run. All procedure from start to finish is doable in ENVI5.5.